# Divide a web page in configurable zones like a dashboard

Tags: html, dashboard

I would like to build a web page to which users can add/remove pre-existing widgets, and organize them on a grid layout.

Are there tools/frameworks that can help doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/home) has a Portlets plugin that will allow you to do that fairly easy.

You can check out the demo here:

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets

Answer (score 1):

Just a correction to the jQuery UI portlets demo that Andres posted since I don't have enough reputation to make a comment.

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets